# How to make PopUP Collapsible?

Tags: html, css, popup, transition, responsive

I am working on a school project and we have to create a static digital-menu for a Bar. Anyways, I made a button and when the user clicks it, a PopUP with the list of all the items shows up(I used the display: none; property):

[image]

The source code for the PopUP is this(I store it inside the index.html file):

```
<div class="menu">
<h2>Our Menu</h2>
<ul>
     <li>
         <label>
             <input type="checkbox" name="">
             <span class="icon"></span>
             <span class="list">Fried Fish With Souce</span>
         </label>
     </li>
     <li>
         <label>
             <input type="checkbox" name="">
             <span class="icon"></span>
             <span class="list">Fresh Traditional Cod And Chips</span>
         </label>
     </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

This is the CSS Source Code:

```
.menu
{
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 380px;
  margin: 25px;
}

h2
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

ul
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: 1px dashed rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border-top: none;
}

ul li
{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 5px 0; 
    font-size: 16px;
}

ul li input[type="checkbox"]
{
    display: none;
}

ul li span.list
{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 5px;
    transition: 0.25s;
    transition-delay: 0.25s;
}

ul li input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ span.list
{
    color: #ccc;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}

ul li span.list:before
{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -100%;
    background: #ff3663;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: 0.25s;
    transition-delay: 0.25s;
}

ul li input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ span.list:before
{
    left: 100%;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}

ul li span.list:after
{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    background: #000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    transform-origin: left;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transition: 0.25s;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}

ul li input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ span.list:after
{
    transform: scaleX(1);
    transition-delay: 0.25s;
}

ul li span.icon
{
    position: relative;
    top: -3px;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #262626;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 2px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

ul li span.icon:before
{
    content: 'x';
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
    left: 4px;
    transform: translateY(-100%);
    transition: 0.25s;
}

ul li input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ span.icon:before
{
    transform: translateY(0);
}
```

This is alright, but all the menu items also have a description, so the source code for the menu should be like this:

```
<li>
    <label>
           <input type="checkbox" name="">
           <span class="icon"></span>
           <span class="list">Fried Fish With Souce</span>
           <span class="itemDescription">THIS IS A DESCRIPTION!!!</span>
    </label>
</li>
```

So, the question becomes: How can I add the description to every item only when that certain item is being checked, and hide the description when that specific item is unchecked? There should be some sort of a Collapsible menu, like an animation/transition. Also, How can I make the whole PopUP responsive on the Horizontal Axis(all the elements should become smaller) BUT also when a new description shows up, all the other items should move down and as a consequence, the PopUP should become longer. I have no idea how to approach this, so, any amount of help in the right direction would be very useful. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Talking about responsiveness you should read [this from w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_grid.asp) that explain how to create a grid system in css.
You can also learn to use a framework like [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/)

All the other things you are trying to do can be done with few lines of javascript code!
This is an example for just one item of the menu:

```
<!--Put this before your </body> tag-->
<script>
// Add a click event listener to the element the id refers to
document.getElementById("menu-item-id").addEventListener("click", function() {
   // Get descriprion reference
   let description = document.getElementById("menu-item-description");
   // If description is visible hide it
   if (description.style.display !== "none") {
      description.style.display = "none";
   }
   // If description is not visible show it
   else {
      description.style.display = "block";
   }
});
</script>
```

You can learn more about addEventListener [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_addeventlistener.asp) and about getElementById [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp)